# Bug with likes and dislikes on careers profile edit page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, tag-dropdown

On the careers profile edit page (http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/), if you are editing your technology "likes" and "dislikes" using IE 10 (on Windows 8/F12 reports IE10 "Standards" mode), the suggestion functionality is over-aggressive on the second and successive technology and will overwrite the first choice instead of updating the current one.

For example, if I were to type "per" in either the like or dislike boxes, and then mouse click on "perl" in the suggestions, and then begin typing "jav" and then click "java" - the box will overwrite the first entry with java and the control will contain "java jav ".  If I had typed "java perl linu" and clicked linux in the dropdown, the control will contain "linux perl linu "

By the way - this doesn't appear to happen with the Tags functionality on meta stackoverflow.

Comment: Yep, I see it. Will work on a fix.

Answer (score 2):

Just tidying up some old bug reports - this one seems to be fixed now.